# Determining the radius of convergence of a series that I don't know how to express in sigma

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

> Problem 1: Consider the ODE: $(1+x^3)y'' -6xy = 0$
>
> > (a) Compute the first $3$ nonzero terms of power series expansion about $x = 0$ for two linearly independent solutions.
> >
> > (b) Use the ratio test to determine the radius of convergence of the series. Could your result
> >     have been predicted by inspection?

The solution for $y = a_0(1+x^3) + a_1(x + \frac{x^4}{2}- \frac{x^7}{14}+ \frac{x^{10}}{35}- \frac{x^{13}}{65}+\cdots)$

In order to use the ratio test $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{a_n (x-x_0)^n}|$$

I need to know how to express $(x + \frac{x^4}{2}- \frac{x^7}{14}+ \frac{x^{10}}{35}- \frac{x^{13}}{65}+\cdots)$ in the sigma form. Am I right?

However, I cannot come up with a proper way to express the equation in a sigma form. Is there an alternate way to perform the ratio test?

Comment: Your ODE is singular at $x=-1$. At least one solution will not converge there. That this implies that the radius of convergence is $1$ requires some further argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a coefficient recursion ($a_{-1}=a_{-2}=0$)
$$
x^n: (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}+(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}-6a_{n-1}=0
\\~\\\iff (n+1)[(n+2)a_{n+2}+(n-4)a_{n-1}]=0
\\~\\\implies
a_{n+3}=-\frac{n-3}{n+3}a_n.
$$
so that $a_2=0$ and thus $a_{3k+2}=0$ for all $k$ and also $a_6=0$ and thus $a_{3k}=0$ for $k\ge 2$.

The remaining part $\sum_ka_{3k+1}x^{3k+1}$ has radius of convergence equal $1$ by the quotient test.

From $(n+3)na_{n+3}=-n(n-3)a_n$ it follows that these products are constant with alternating sign, thus $a_{3k+1}=(-1)^{k-1}\frac{2}{(3k+1)(3k-2)}a_1$ giving the solution as
$$
y(x)=a_0(1+x^3)+2a_1\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}x^{3k+1}}{(3k+1)(3k-2)}.
$$

---

In the normalized form, $y''-\frac{6x}{x^3+1}y=0$ has analytical coefficients with convergence radius $1$, thus any solutions are also analytical with at least the same convergence radius, and at least one solution with exactly this radius.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How did you know that $a_6 = 0$?

Comment: Because $6a_6=-(3-3)a_3=0$. And once there is a zero in this recursion, all other entries of this subsequence are zero.

Comment: Silly me. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm trying to get the radius of convergence. What do you mean by quotient test? I tried googling it but it doesn't give me the exact explanation. Do you mean ratio test?

Comment: So far, I have got $$\left| \frac{\frac{1}{(3k+4)(3k+1)}}{\frac{1}{(3k+1)(3k-2)}}x^3\right| < 1$$, which is using ratio test. This yields: $$\left| \frac{3k-2}{3k+4}x^3 \right|<1$$. I am not sure how to go from here, or what to do with $k$. Can you please direct me?

Comment: Hold on, I think I know how to do it... I will keep it updated. Just gimme some time...

Comment: Yes, the ratio test, as the coefficients are rational functions of $k$ and nothing power related. The root test would work as well, but requires some preparation. // You need to put $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ in front of the left side, leading to $|x|^3$.

Comment: $$\lim  _{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{1}{(3k+4)(3k+1)}}{\frac{1}{(3k+1)(3k-2)}}x^3\right| < 1 \longleftrightarrow \left|x^3 \right|<1$$. And therefore, the radius of convergence of this sum is $1$?